# Hibernate with json data and Spring MVC

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am a newbiew to hibernate and REST. Currently I have a REST controller which is in Spring MVC, Hibernate for ORM and json to call the REST API.

When I try to pass an entity in the form of json message to the REST controller and the entity contains the simple types (ex int, String etc), the entity gets persisted through Hibernate.

But I don now know how to get this working when the entity contains other entities and has a one-to-many relationship.

Since the input will be json message, and I assume that the json message for one entiry will contain the other entity, how to I persist both the entities with relationship using Hibernate?

Please let me know with some examples.

Comment: Please show the source code

Answer (score 0):

You should use cascaded insert.
See hibernate documentation on "cascading".

You can see perfect example here:[Insert Order and Items in single UI form](http://upida.cloudapp.net:8080/org.upida.example.knockout/order/create?clientId=1)
You can download code in upida.codeplex.com

Comment: No problem ! Probably it is not the best thing that you need, because this example is done using multiple 3rd parties: Angular, Upida, Jackson, etc. But you can definitely find hibernate mapping with cascading there. Just go to upida.codeplex.com

Comment: I downloaded the code but finding it difficult to set up the code base. Its throwing lot of compile time errors.. Please help me out..

Comment: Just see the classes in the domain package, and mapping files in the mapping package. You will find out how to make cascading mapping there, between Order and OrderItem. or give me your email I will help you to set up everything. Do you have Maven installed ?

Comment: Yes I have maven installed. my email address is pradeep.kumar44@gmail.com